# custom MFT in windows phone app

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, ms-media-foundation

I need to create a custom MFT because it's the only way to get raw frames in YUV format on windows phone 8.1 (Runtime, no silverlight).

I know it's not easy but I don't have any other choice.

I'm trying to learn for the example of GrayscaleTransform: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Media-Capture-Sample-adf87622

But I don't really understand how does it work. 
The only thing I see which has a reference on the C++ Grayscale in the Application is :

_mediaCaptureMgr.AddEffectAsync(Windows.Media.Capture.MediaStreamType.Photo,"GrayscaleTransform.GrayscaleEffect", null);

There isn't any instance of the Grayscale created, or any called to any methods.
So, I'm wondering how does is work ?

Thanks,

Sebastien

Answer (score 2):

The MediaCapture sample registers GrayscaleTransform.GrayscaleEffect in its Pakage.appxmanifest, line 35:

```
<Extension Category="windows.activatableClass.inProcessServer">
  <InProcessServer>
    <Path>GrayscaleTransform.dll</Path>
    <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="GrayscaleTransform.GrayscaleEffect" ThreadingModel="both" />
  </InProcessServer>
</Extension>
```

This lets the MediaCapture object find the added effect and add it to the media pipeline.

An app can also register MFTs with the [MediaExtensionManager class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.mediaextensionmanager.aspx).

Comment: But where is the Grayscale instantiated ? I can see its constructor, destructor, dozens of methods, but I don't see any main fonction ?

Comment: It's instantiated internal to the MediaCapture element based on the call to AddEffectAsync. It's then added to the media pipeline and called between the decoder and the renderer.

Comment: But who call the methods in the Grayscale class ?

Comment: That's called internal to the media session. The app triggers this by calling AddEffectAsync on the MediaCapture element, and then the MediaCapture element adds the MFT into the pipeline. See the chart at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819455(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: So when the AddEffectAsync calls the custom MFT, it is instantiate and place into the pipeline ? Where is the input and the output of this MFT in the cpp file ? I don't want this GreyScale effect but just capturing the raw frame in YUV format, can you please give me some hint ?

Comment: [CGrayscale](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Media-Capture-Sample-adf87622/sourcecode?fileId=52174&pathId=862544182) implements [IMFTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms696260(v=vs.85).aspx), and has ProcessInput/ProcessOutput methods. ProcessOutput calls into the OnProcessOutput, which converts image. If you only need one frame, you may want to capture photo in [NV12](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/windows.media.mediaproperties.imageencodingproperties.createuncompressed.aspx).

Comment: What if I need to get frames in 30 fps ?

Comment: Then you write a custom MFT or a preview/capture sink.

Comment: This is really a different question than was origianlly asked. You might want to update the question or ask it separately. AddEffectAsync doesn't directly call the custom MFT, but it tells the MediaCapture element to add the custom MFT to the pipeline when it starts the capture. If you run in the native (not managed) debugger you can put breakpoints on the ProcessOutput and ProcessInput methods to follow the code flow.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking where can you find the Grayscale cpp file itself.  In the solution explorer you can find it under MediaExtensions/MFExtensions/GrayscaleTransform/GrayscaleTransform.Shared/

There you will see Grayscale.cpp and all of its functions. Hopefully viewing those will help.